# Halfopen createConenction doesn't end

Tags: node.js, sockets

I'm trying to use 'net.createConnection' with a half-open connection and terminate it if there's a timeout. But 'end' event looks like not working at all. Here's code:

```
router.get('/api-route/:host', (req, res) => {
  const WEB_PORT = 4444;
  const OPEN_PORT_STATUS = true;
  const CLOSE_PORT_STATUS = false;
  const TIMEOUT = 2000;

  let answer = {
    host: req.params.host,
    port: WEB_PORT,
    status: false,
  };

  const client = net.createConnection(
    {
      port: WEB_PORT,
      host: req.params.host,
      allowHalOpen: true,
      timeout: TIMEOUT,
    },
    () => {
      client.end();
      answer.status = OPEN_PORT_STATUS;
    }
  );

  client.on('timeout', () => {
    client.end();
    answer.status = CLOSE_PORT_STATUS;
  });

  client.on('error', (e: any) => {
    client.end();
    answer.status = CLOSE_PORT_STATUS;
  });

  client.on('end', () => {
    res.json(answer);
  });
});
```

'client.end()' doesn't end connection neither on 'timeout' event, nor on 'error'. And I don't understand why. This code is almost identical to Node.js docs but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it. If the server is unresponsive on a specific port, you will send a FIN request but the server will not budge - since it's not responding at all. The only way to terminate a connection is to destroy with "destroy" and throw and error.